# How to check if a NON LTI System is invertible?

Tags: homework, non-linear, inverse

$T\left\{x\left(t\right)\right\}=x\left(t\right)cos\left(\omega t\right)+1$
Can I say that? or there is another way?
$x\left(t\right)=\frac{T\left\{x\left(t\right)\right\}-1}{cos\left(\omega t\right)}$
I just do not understand if that is the way to see if a non LTI system is invertible. or there is another way ( we barely learnt about this ).

EDIT: This is atleast what I understood from CHAT-GPT, because I have no other source for it sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What GPT did is basic algebraic manipulation (that too nonsensical) and is in fact not a valid check for invertability.

Given that this system is neither linear nor time-invariant, checking for invertibility is not straight forward. The main issue is the operation of dividing by $\cos(\omega t)$ which must be valid for all $t$. This means that $\cos(\omega t)$ must never be zero, because division by zero is undefined. The cosine function, however, is obviously zero at $ t = (2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2} \omega$ for any integer $k$, which means there most definitely will be points in time where $\cos(\omega t) = 0$ and the equation for $ x(t)$ is not defined. Therefore, the system is not invertible over the entire time domain because you cannot recover $x(t)$ at these points.

Comment: Oh I see.
Thank you.
But if the denominator was never zero for all, so it was invertible, right?
Like if $cos(\omega t)$ never existed

Comment: @BenShaines that depends on the system. Your example system is memoryless, and that's very rare. If your system has memory, some inputs might cancel themselves out, and then it's also not invertible.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks!